# Does React re-render the entire top-level component or just the individual components within which change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, create-react-app

I was wondering in terms of efficiency, if I have just this line in a file, as set up by create-react-app,

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and a class in another file called App, which contains call to many other classes and perhaps calls to classes from other files, will a small change in one of those sub-classes require a re-rendering of the entire App class, or just that individual class or classes that require a change. I hope this makes some sense. Thanks!

Comment: Typically, it will rerender the component that you called `this.setState` on, plus that component's descendents. If you want to avoid the descendents rerendering, you can do so by writing `shouldComponentUpdate` functions

Answer (score 0):

Generally react rerenders tree if `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true. It means that Classical react component `class Component1 extends React.Component`, rerenders every time. If you want the child components to be rerendered only if its properties changes,  you should use React.PureComponent which provides `shouldComponentUpdate` which makes shallow comparison of properties.

Comment: This seems to me to be really stupid, since it kind of destroys the reasoning behind React being friendly to programming novices if the speed-up/efficiency is only found with people that really understand the DOM and so forth. Is React just glorified for a feature which most people don't even take advantage of?